# How do you label points in a scatterChart built using ng2-chart

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have built this scatterChart using ng2-chart:
[image]
What I want is:  Display a 'name' next to each black point in the graph.

> Chart.component.html:

```
<!-- chart.js -->
<div style="display: block;">
  <canvas
    baseChart
    [datasets]="scatterChartData"
    [options]="scatterChartOptions"
    [chartType]="scatterChartType"
  >
  </canvas>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="typo-line">
    <h4><p class="category"><b>Légende</b></p></h4>
  </div>
    <p class="text-primary">
      R-1 Tremblement de terre
    </p>
    <p class="text-primary">
      R-2 Température et humidité
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Chart.component.ts: The code that creates the black dots:

```
public scatterChartType: ChartType = "scatter";
  constructor(private data: AnalyseRisqueService) {}
  probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow:number[][]=[]
  ngOnInit() {
     this.data.currentProbaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow.subscribe(receivedProbaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow=>
      (this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow=receivedProbaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow)
      )
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.chart.chart.data.datasets[0].data = [
        { x: this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow[0][0], y: this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow[0][1] },
        { x: this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow[1][0], y: this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow[1][1] },
        { x: this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow[2][0], y: this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow[2][1] },
        { x: this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow[3][0], y: this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow[3][1] },
        { x: this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow[4][0], y: this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow[4][1] },
        { x: this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow[5][0], y: this.probaGraviteValuesIndexedByRow[5][1] },
      ]
      this.chart.chart.update();
  }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide a working demo on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: @Viqas https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-scatter-template .That's basically the same example.

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip for points are provided using the `options` binding for canvas.

Add the tooltip as a callback to your `scatterChartOptions` object like so in your TS file:

```
public scatterChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (item, data) => 
        {
          console.log(item);
          return 'Label: ' + item.xLabel + ' ' + item.yLabel
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

This should display a simple label with your x and y values.

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-scatter-template-wy927p) working StackBlitz.

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: yes thank you. It helped. However, I need to give each point its own specific label. if (point1) then (label1) ;

Comment: I tried to use the item variable. But, console.log(item) doesn't log anything . Any idea why?

Comment: Oh great! Super! I can now specify what label to show based on the parameters inside the item object. I believe this has been solved. Thank you so much :)

Comment: {xLabel: 1, yLabel: 1, label: "1", value: "1", index: 1, …}
the index represents the point index . That should solve my problem. I will post an answer if this works

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Viqas's tip, I managed to solve this:

```
   tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (item, data) =>
        {
          if (item.index===0){
            return 'Risque: 0'
          }
          else if (item.index===1) {
            return 'Risque: 1'
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This way, I can control what label to display depending on which point I want.

Comment: Or simply :           return ('Risque ' + item.index)